# Tag based clustering with overlaps (soft clustering)

Tags: python, algorithm, tags, cluster-analysis

I am looking for an algorithm to cluster twitter feeds based on their hashtags, where hashtags would not be strictly assigned only to one cluster.

Very simple example:

- feed 1: #food #vegetable
- feed 2: #food #vegetable
- feed 3: #food #fruit
- feed 4: #food #fruit

And the result I would like to get would be:

- cluster 1: #food #vegetable
- cluster 2: #food #fruit

Of course, in reality I can have hundreds of thousands of feeds and several thousands of possible hashtags.

I was trying various methods in scikit-learn (k-means, spectral clustering, agglomerative clustering) using similarity matrix like:

```
               #food | #vegetable | #fruit |
#food            1   |    1/2     |   1/2  |
#vegetable      1/2  |     1      |    0   |
#fruit          1/2  |     0      |    1   |
```

All these algorithms works but they create disjoint clusters (each hashtag belongs to only one cluster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can consider that your hashtags are a description and run a LDA algorithm on it. It will create topics containing multiple hashtags and each hashtags can be found in multiple topics.
- you can create a weighted graph from you hashtags. All you hashtags are the nodes of this graph and the edge are incremented when hashtags are present in the same feed. From this graph you can use multiple community detection algorithm that allows community overlapping (k-click for exemple)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like the community detection idea. Could you maybe post some code example?

Comment: Python comes with NetworkX, it could helps you a bit : https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/community.html

Comment: I will try it, thanks. What do you think is the best way to choose parameter `k` in `k_clique_communities` algorithm? Considering that I have around around 10K hashtags. I wonder if it is not even too big for this method.

Comment: You can give it a try, the result will strongly depends on the structure of your graph. 
To choose k you can try some simple stuff like sqrt(n), n/(1+log2(n))